# Two identical queries returning two different values. C# .Net Core EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

**Scenario**

This is for a discord bot using the DSharp library. Now in this instance, when I chat a command on discord as `!status testmenu` the context's content will be `!status testmenu`. So in order to isolate the `command` and `prefix` from the message body I am creating a new string `message` which holds only the message body(`testmenu`) as shown in this line.

```
 string message = context.Message.Content.Replace(context.Message.Content.Substring(0, (context.Command.Name.Length + 1)), string.Empty);
```

However simultaneously, the parameter `content` also returns just the message body alone. So right before the `if` condition both `content` and `message` are equal, including case sensitivity wise as well.

So both `message` and `content` both have a string value of `testmenu`.

*Reason for duplicates*: Controlled testing.

**Problem**

When I query the database with the first string, `message` I get a null return. 
However when I query the database with the second string `content` (from the parameter) I get the appropriate record returned. However bear in mind, again, both `message` and `content` are identical strings, case sensitivity included.

I tried swapping the query statements between each other just to ensure it wasn't a sequential error and it was not. It's the same result each time. The query with the parameter string always returns a value while the query with the `message` string returns null. And yes I have indeed put a break point right before the "if" statement just to ensure the `message` string isn't null and it was not. It had the same value as context.

```
    [Command("status")]
    public async Task Status(CommandContext context, string content)
    {
        string message = context.Message.Content.Replace(context.Message.Content.Substring(0, (context.Command.Name.Length + 1)), string.Empty);
        Models.Menu SelectedMenu;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {           
           //returns null
            SelectedMenu = await _context.Menus.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Menu_Name.ToLower().Contains(message)).ConfigureAwait(false);

        }

        //returns appropriate record
        var menu = await _context.Menus.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Menu_Name.ToLower().Contains(context.Message.Content)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(menu.Status.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Comment: Evans, I have edited the question, the way it made more sense. Let me know if this was okay

Comment: Yes that's perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake however at first glance, not so noticeable.

`string message = context.Message.Content.Replace(context.Message.Content.Substring(0, (context.Command.Name.Length + 1)), string.Empty);`

`context.Message.Content`, of which "Content" has a value `"!status testmenu"`

`context.Command.Name` has a value of `"status"` and I am adding + 1 to the substring to remove the initial "!" as well. So now the string has a value `" testmenu"`

As you can see here, I am not trimming this string, so there are still white spaces left at the beginning.

To the human eye in visual studio, when you hover your mouse while debugging, over the variables they **may seem identical but it's not the case** since there was indeed a white space at the beginning, hence why I was receiving a null value when I tried to query the data.

Once I trimmed the string and ran the query everything worked as it should.